# Proving a trigonometric inequality between $\cos$ and $\sin$ and involving a constant

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Let $x,y\in[0,\pi/2]$ such that

$$\cos(x)\le n\cos(y).$$

> Deduce that
> $$\sin(y)\le c_n\sin(x)$$
> where $c_n>0$ is a constant depending only on $n$.

Maybe $c_n=n$, maybe not. I strongly suspect this result to be true when I draw the problem in a trigonometric circle, but I can not find a way to prove it analytically. Any hints would be of great help!

Comment: Martin R is right. There is no such constant $c_n$.

Comment: @egreg You are all rights, I have edited to change the first statement. Sorry about that.

Comment: Is the first inequality valid $\forall x,y$ or for a particular pair ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust for a particular pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the given relations,

$$n\ge\frac{\cos x}{\cos y}$$ and

$$c_n\ge\frac{\sin y}{\sin x}.$$

Without more information on $x$ and $y$, the two ratios can take any non-negative value independently of each other, and there is nothing more we can say.